# I want to get the master items rather from my dynamic module

Tags: babaganoush-sitefinity

FooFooManager.Speakers.GetAll() gets the live items however I want the master items

This doesn't work FooFooManager.Speakers.GetAll().Where(s => s.Status == ContentLifecycleStatus.Master);

How can I get the master items?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can pass in a filter before it reaches Babaganoush, like this:

```
BabaManagers.News.GetAll(
    filter: x => x.Status == ContentLifecycleStatus.Master
);
```

More details can be found here: http://babaganoush.falafel.com/documentation/tutorials/how-to-retrieve-data

Comment: That would be perfect but unfortunately it does't return any items... at least for dynamicmodels anyway... is this a bug @Basem?